# Select difference of days between two dates where date is not in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select a list of dates between two dates (startDate and endDate), where the date does not appear in a seperate list (holidays).

For example I have used:

```
select dateadd(day, number, StartDate)
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
        where name is null
    ) n
where dateadd(day, number, StartDate) < EndDate
```

Which gives me a list of dates between the two dates. However I want to take out and count the days where not in a list of holidays dates.

Thanks,

Firstcape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query 1:**

```
DECLARE 
      @DateFrom DATETIME
    , @DateTo DATETIME

SELECT 
      @DateFrom = '20130101'
    , @DateTo = '20130131'

DECLARE @holidays TABLE ([Date] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @holidays ([Date])
VALUES ('20130101')

SELECT [Date]
FROM (
    SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, sv.number, t.DateFrom)
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              DateFrom = @DateFrom
            , diff = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateFrom, @DateTo)
    ) t
    JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values sv ON sv.number <= diff
    WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'
) t2
WHERE t2.[Date] NOT IN (SELECT h.[Date] FROM @holidays h)
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT t2.[Date]
FROM (
    SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, sv.number, t.DateFrom)
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              DateFrom = @DateFrom
            , diff = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DateFrom, @DateTo)
    ) t
    JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values sv ON sv.number <= diff
    WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'
) t2
LEFT JOIN @holidays h ON h.[Date] = t2.[Date]
WHERE h.[Date] IS NULL
```

**Output:**

```
Date
-----------------------
2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000
2013-01-06 00:00:00.000
2013-01-07 00:00:00.000
2013-01-08 00:00:00.000
...
```

Comment: Thanks this works for the set dates, but I need to do this for multiple members with different Start and End dates? Such as a seperate query with a list of ID's and Start and End dates.

Comment: Please provide your data with Start & End dates.

Comment: Ok sorry ignore that last comment. I was confusing myself with some extra data I needed. Thanks for your help!